# String manipulation in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a

```
string_temp="00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF"
X=AB
```

I need to replace 5 and 6th element (index can be anything) of string with X content.
output should be "0011AB33445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF"

Please help me with sed or any other easy method to do this.

Comment: Which shell are you using? A solution using sed/awk/perl would be more portable but this can be done natively in bash.

Comment: i can easily do it by converting string to array, but bash is not enabled on my hw.

Comment: i can do sed s/./5/A to replace 5th element, but i want to replace 5th and 6th in single command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you've attempted to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed. Replace next 2 characters after position 4 with $X:

```
string_temp="00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF"
X="AB"
echo "$string_temp" | sed -r "s/(.{4}).{2}/\1$X/"
```

Output:

```
0011AB33445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
```

Avoid `sed`'s special characters (e.g.: `/`) in $string_temp and $X.

Comment: No need to involve a second back reference, eliminate it from both sides and the same result is returned.